# Can laser measure find a distance to a rotated surface?

Tags: laser

I want to make a robot that solves a hand-made maze, so that I want to provide it a LIDAR component to measure the distance to read the environment. Before buying a component I want to know if it's capable of measuring distance to a rotated surface. Under rotated surface I mean a wall that is not perfectly aligned with the LIDAR emitter, see the image

[image]

Is it even possible that the light beam ever reach the LIDAR's receiver and how accurate the measurement can be?